# Unable to change the android time picker mode 24hrs mode to AM_PM mode

Tags: java, android, android-timepicker

I'm working with the timepicker dialouge here but for some reason which i don't understand, i couldn't change the mode of the `time picker` to that of `AM_PM mode`
I have tried the code `timepicker.setIs24HourView(false);`
Here is my code

```
onCreate(..){
button.onClickListe..(new...(){
showTimePickerDialog();
});}


 public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                true);
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
       view.setIs24HourView(false);//TODO not working <-------- This code is not working here
        setTimeString(hourOfDay, minute, 0);

        timeView.setText(timeString);
    }
}


`private void showTimePickerDialog() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}`}
```

Comment: try to set false instead of true for AP PM in TimePickerDialog constructor like :  return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,false);

Comment: you mean changing the core code??

Comment: Please check updated comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check last parameter in `TimePickerDialog` constructor which is for 24 hours format, So disable 24 hours format with passing `false` value for last parameter :

```
return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,false);
```

Comment: @Virus,Glad to help you.

Comment: sir, can you please let me know one more thing..how do i make the selected date show in 12hrs format

Comment: have you try this code it still given 24 hours time on time set.

Comment: yes that's what i am asking... the layout comes perfect as i wanted but not the time

Comment: Try to use HOUR instead of HOUR_OF_DAY when you get hour from Calendar.

Comment: Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20629289/24-hour-format-to-12-hour-format