# Android SimpleDateFormat returning incorrect time between midnight and 1am

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

SOLVED
I have found that between midnight and 1am my device returns a time 1 hour later (the other 23 hours a day it returns correctly). More weirdly it returns correctly if I use `kk` instead of `HH` (though the resulting string is no use to me)

Code I am running: (in this instance `strFormat` matches the hardcoded string in `df3`)

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(strFormat, Locale.US);
SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm", Locale.US);
SimpleDateFormat df3 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.US);

Date d = c.getTime();
String s = d.toString();
String ret = df.format(c.getTime());
String ret2 = df.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
String ret3 = df2.format(c.getTime());
String ret4 = df3.format(c.getTime());
String r1 = ""+c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
```

These return:

```
s = "Thu Jan 07 00:39:32 GMT-11:00 2016"
ret = "2016-01-07 01:39:32"
ret2 = "2016-01-07 01:39:32"
ret3 = "2016-01-07 24:39"
ret4 = "2016-01-07 01:39:32.525"
r1 = "0"
```

After 1am these return:

```
s = "Thu Jan 07 01:07:09 GMT-11:00 2016"
ret = "2016-01-07 01:07:09"
ret2 = "2016-01-07 01:07:09"
ret3 = "2016-01-07 01:07"
ret4 = "2016-01-07 01:07:09.606"
r1 = "1"
```

Any help in what I have done wrong/what is going wrong greatly appreciated.

UPDATE

changing code to:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(strFormat, Locale.US);
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm zzz", Locale.US);
        df2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        SimpleDateFormat df3 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS zzz", Locale.US);
        df3.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        Date d = c.getTime();
        String s = d.toString();
        String ret = df.format(c.getTime());
        String ret2 = df.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        String ret3 = df2.format(c.getTime());
        String ret4 = df3.format(c.getTime());
        String r1 = ""+c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        return ret;
```

I get the same results:

```
s = "Fri Jan 08 00:52:05 GMT 2016"
ret = "2016-01-08 01:52:05"
ret2 = "2016-01-08 01:52:05"
ret3 = "2016-01-08 24:52 GMT"
ret4 = "2016-01-08 01:52:05.169 GMT"
r1 = "0"
```

and

```
s = "Fri Jan 08 01:03:23 GMT 2016"
ret = "2016-01-08 01:03:23"
ret2 = "2016-01-08 01:03:23"
ret3 = "2016-01-08 01:03 GMT"
ret4 = "2016-01-08 01:03:23.547 GMT"
r1 = "1"
```

so the problem seems to be unrelated to TimeZone

Comment: What's your TimeZone?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't change anything in the code in those 40 minutes?

Comment: Add "ZZZZ" to see the timezone in SimpleDateFormat, maybe it's different

Comment: I am actually in GMT - I have been changing the timezone on the device to see if that had any effect (between those 2 runs I changed the time on the device - they were run a couple of minutes apart)

Comment: I've tried your code on Samsung S3 that runs 4.1.3 and and on emulator with 4.1.2 and everything is OK. Can you try another device?

Comment: Agree with @TDG, I use your code above in my phone and emulator (both 4.1.2), logcat `s: Wed Jan 13 00:34:09 GMT-11:00 2016
ret: 2016-01-13 00:34:09.652 GMT-11:00
ret2: 2016-01-13 00:34:09.653 GMT-11:00
ret3: 2016-01-13 24:34
ret4: 2016-01-13 00:34:09.652
r1: 0`. You can try another device or post more code to check, or check your phone settings

Comment: I have multiple of the same device (its a custom tablet for the industry) and am seeing this across all of them (differing time zones etc.). I have also run this on a G3 (running 5.0) and the values are correct

Comment: @Collett89 check the settings of date and time of all of your devices, maybe they have differents time zone.

Comment: What is the version of the [Android API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#ApiLevels) on your target device?

Comment: @morido I am compiling against version 23 - I will try different versions to see if it has any effect - The devices are running version 4.1.2 (api 16)

Comment: @JJ86 There are a few different time zones in use - but the time zone should not matter in this instance (I have tried several and all show this problem)

Comment: `'H'` isn't supported on API Levels <=17. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16764435/5717099) (SO) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55843) (Android Bugtracker). Other that that I am suspecting the described behavior may be related to [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=158265) bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lay with the tablets themselves - they have extra sensors built in that once accessed messed up the internal clock.
Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 4):

May be you have to set the timeZone for your dateFormat objects.

I tried this :

```
    Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-11:00"), Locale.US);
    c.set(2016, 0, 7, 00, 39, 32);
    Date date  = c.getTime();

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.US);
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-11:00"));
    SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm", Locale.US);
    df2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-11:00"));
    SimpleDateFormat df3 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.US);
    df3.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-11:00"));

    String ret = df.format(date.getTime());
    String ret2 = df.format(date.getTime());
    String ret3 = df2.format(date.getTime());
    String ret4 = df3.format(date.getTime());

    System.out.println("  ret : "+ret);
    System.out.println("  ret2 : "+ret2);
    System.out.println("  ret3 kk: "+ret3);
    System.out.println("  ret4 : "+ret4);
```

The result is correct :

```
 ret : Thu Jan 07 00:39:32 GMT-11:00 2016
 ret2 : Thu Jan 07 00:39:32 GMT-11:00 2016
 ret3 kk: 2016-01-07 24:39
 ret4 : 2016-01-07 00:39:32.217
```

Comment: using `df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));` I am still getting the same result

Answer (score 1):

Idk... honestly. I tried recreting your problem, but in Eclipse on PC, not in Android. This is what I used:

```
    Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.ofOffset("", ZoneOffset.ofHours(-11))), Locale.US);
    c.set(2016, 0, 7, 0, 7);

    String strFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS";


    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(strFormat, Locale.US);
    SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm", Locale.US);
    SimpleDateFormat df3 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.US);

    Date d = c.getTime();
    String s = d.toString();
    String ret = df.format(c.getTime());
    String ret2 = df.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    String ret3 = df2.format(c.getTime());
    String ret4 = df3.format(c.getTime());
    String r1 = ""+c.get(Calendar.HOUR);

    System.out.printf("s = %s%nret = %s%nret2 = %s%nret3 = %s%nret4 = %s%nr1 = %s%n%n", s, ret, ret2, ret3, ret4, r1);

    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.ofOffset("", ZoneOffset.ofHours(-11))));
    df2.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.ofOffset("", ZoneOffset.ofHours(-11))));
    df3.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.ofOffset("", ZoneOffset.ofHours(-11))));

    d = c.getTime();
    s = d.toString();
    ret = df.format(c.getTime());
    ret2 = df.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    ret3 = df2.format(c.getTime());
    ret4 = df3.format(c.getTime());
    r1 = ""+c.get(Calendar.HOUR);

    System.out.printf("s = %s%nret = %s%nret2 = %s%nret3 = %s%nret4 = %s%nr1 = %s%n%n", s, ret, ret2, ret3, ret4, r1);

    c.set(2016, 0, 7, 1, 7);

    d = c.getTime();
    s = d.toString();
    ret = df.format(c.getTime());
    ret2 = df.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    ret3 = df2.format(c.getTime());
    ret4 = df3.format(c.getTime());
    r1 = ""+c.get(Calendar.HOUR);

    System.out.printf("s = %s%nret = %s%nret2 = %s%nret3 = %s%nret4 = %s%nr1 = %s%n", s, ret, ret2, ret3, ret4, r1);
```

And this is what I got:

```
s = Thu Jan 07 12:07:58 CET 2016
ret = 2016-01-07 12:07:58.662
ret2 = 2016-01-07 17:55:58.697
ret3 = 2016-01-07 12:07
ret4 = 2016-01-07 12:07:58.662
r1 = 0

s = Thu Jan 07 12:07:58 CET 2016
ret = 2016-01-07 00:07:58.662
ret2 = 2016-01-07 05:55:58.718
ret3 = 2016-01-07 24:07
ret4 = 2016-01-07 00:07:58.662
r1 = 0

s = Thu Jan 07 13:07:58 CET 2016
ret = 2016-01-07 01:07:58.662
ret2 = 2016-01-07 05:55:58.722
ret3 = 2016-01-07 01:07
ret4 = 2016-01-07 01:07:58.662
r1 = 1
```

Maybe there is a problem in your SimpleDateFormat, which uses a different timezone... This is really interesting.

Comment: using `df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));` I am still getting the same results

Answer (score 0):

possibly:
c.getTime() returns your current time, and SimpleDateFormat formats it to Locale.US. US is a big country with different time zones and your device time zone could be different from Locale.US !
Remove Locale.US and keep us posted.

Comment: I don't think so. Defining a Locale just formats the date differently, it doesn't change the timezone.